# TSQL -- Extract JSON values for unknown/dynamic key in sub-object (not an array)

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using DataTables, DataTables Editor, JavaScript, and MSSQL 2016.

I'd like to parse this string in SQL Server:

```
{
    "action":"edit",
    "data": { 
                "2019-08-03":{ 
                                "Description":"sdfsafasdfasdf",
                                "FirstFrozenStep":"333"
                             }
            }
}
```

I don't know how to access the key "2019-08-03".  This represents the primary key, or the `DT_RowId` in DataTables Editor.  It's dynamic... It could change.

Historically, I have just manipulated the data in JavaScript to a FLAT object, which is WAY easier to parse in SQL Server:

```
{
     "action":"edit",
     "DT_RowId":"2019-08-03",
     "Description":"sdfsafasdfasdf",
     "FirstFrozenStep":"333"
}
```

HOWEVER, I would like to know how to use `json_query`, `json_value`, and `openjson()` to drill down to the "dynamic" key mentioned above, and then access its values.

Here are all my FAILED attempts:

```
declare
    @jsonRequest nvarchar(max) = '{"action":"edit","data":{"2019-08-03":{"Description":"sdfsafasdfasdf","FirstFrozenStep":"333"}}}'
    ,@json2 nvarchar(max) = '{"2019-08-03":{"Description":"sdfsafasdfasdf","FirstFrozenStep":"333"}}'
    ,@jsonEASY nvarchar(max) = '{"action":"edit","DT_RowId":"2019-08-03","Description":"sdfsafasdfasdf","FirstFrozenStep":"333"}'


    select
        json_value(@jsonRequest, '$.action') as [action]
        --,json_value(@jsonRequest, '$.data.[0]') as [action]
        --,json_query(@jsonRequest, '$.data[0]')
        --,json_query(@jsonRequest, '$.data.[0]')
        --,json_query(@jsonRequest, '$.data[0].Description')
        --,json_query(@jsonRequest, '$.data.Description')
        --,json_query(@jsonRequest, '$.data.[0].Description')


select
    [Key]
    ,Value
    ,Type
    --,json_query(value, '$')
from
    openjson(@jsonRequest)



SELECT x.[Key], x.[Value]
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonRequest, '$') AS x;

select
    x.[Key]
    ,x.[Value]
    --,json_query(x.value, '$')
    --,(select * from openjson(x.value))
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonRequest, '$') AS x;

SELECT x.[Key], x.[Value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json2, '$') AS x;


    select
        json_value(@jsonEASY, '$.action') as [action]
        ,json_value(@jsonEASY, '$.DT_RowId') as [DT_RowId]
        ,json_value(@jsonEASY, '$.Description') as [Description]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most explicit and type-safe approach might be this:

I define your JSON with two *dynamic* keys

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{
    "action":"edit",
    "data": { 
                "2019-08-03":{ 
                                "Description":"sdfsafasdfasdf",
                                "FirstFrozenStep":"333"
                             },
                "2019-08-04":{ 
                                "Description":"blah4",
                                "FirstFrozenStep":"444"
                             }
            }
}';
```

--the query

```
SELECT A.[action]
      ,B.[key]
      ,C.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH([action]  NVARCHAR(100)
                         ,[data]    NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(A.[data]) B 
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(B.[value]) WITH([Description] NVARCHAR(100)
                                     ,FirstFrozenStep INT) C;
```

The result

```
action  key         Description     FirstFrozenStep
edit    2019-08-03  sdfsafasdfasdf  333
edit    2019-08-04  blah4           444
```

The idea in short:

- The first `OPENJSON()` will return the two *first-level-keys* under the alias `A`. The `data` element is returned `AS JSON`, which allows to proceed with this later.
- The second `OPENJSON()` gets `A.[data]` as input and is needed to get hands on the `key`, which is your date.
- The third `OPENJSON()` now gets `B.[value]` as input.

The `WITH`-clause allows to read the inner elements implicitly pivoted and typed.

**In general**: In generic data containers it is **no good idea to use descriptive parts as content**. This is possible and might look clever, but it was much better to place your date as content within a `date`-key.

Comment: I'm getting this message:  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

Comment: @raydlevel5 But not because of With **within** an OPENJSON statement. This must be something else...

Comment: SORRY, I executed when attached on a DB that had the wrong "version"... will report back.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it works, and you've explained a tool that I can use in the future (outer apply).  I totally agree about your statement against using generic keys; however, the request you're seeing is "raw" and built by DataTables Editor.  Since I have the option to manipulate the request before it hits SQL, I will probably continue "flattening" the data to make it easier to parse.... BUT you've provided a way for us to gain access to generic keys!!!

Comment: @raydlevel5 Just one more reason against content-keys: They are nvarchar in any case. Normal content is in a way *typed* (e.g. by the way a date is formatted) and you can read it with WITH in a type-safe way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OUTER APPLY to get to the next level in JSON:

```
SELECT L1.[key], L2.[key], L2.[value]
FROM openjson(@json,'$.data') AS L1
OUTER APPLY openjson(L1.[value]) AS L2
```

It will return:

```
key         key             value  
2019-08-03  Description     sdfsafasdfasdf  
2019-08-03  FirstFrozenStep 333
```